# Print subsequent group in regex match, the text occurring after the found pattern using Python

Tags: python, regex

At present, my Python script looks like this:

```
import re
data = open('toy.json', 'r')

for line in data: 
    m = re.search('\"gas\"', line)
    if m:
        found = m.group(0)
        print(found)
```

And my data looks like this (it's not valid JSON, which is why I'm parsing it with `regex`):

```
{
  "blockNumber": "1941794",
  "blockHash": "0x41ee74e34cbf9ef4116febea958dbc260e2da3a6bf6f601bfaeb2cd9ab944a29",
  "hash": "0xf2b5b8fb173e371cbb427625b0339f6023f8b4ec3701b7a5c691fa9cef9daf63",
  "from": "0x3c0cbb196e3847d40cb4d77d7dd3b386222998d9",
  "to": "0x2ba24c66cbff0bda0e3053ea07325479b3ed1393",
  "gas": "121000",
  "gasUsed": "21000",
  "gasPrice": "20000000000",
  "input": "",
  "logs": [],
  "nonce": "14",
  "value": "0x24406420d09ce7440000",
  "timestamp": "2016-07-24 20:28:11 UTC"
}
{
  "blockNumber": "1941716",
  "blockHash": "0x75e1602cad967a781f4a2ea9e19c97405fe1acaa8b9ad333fb7288d98f7b49e3",
  "hash": "0xf8f2a397b0f7bb1ff212b6bcc57e4a56ce3e27eb9f5839fef3e193c0252fab26",
  "from": "0xa0480c6f402b036e33e46f993d9c7b93913e7461",
  "to": "0xb2ea1f1f997365d1036dd6f00c51b361e9a3f351",
  "gas": "121000",
  "gasUsed": "21000",
  "gasPrice": "20000000000",
  "input": "",
  "logs": [],
  "nonce": "1",
  "value": "0xde0b6b3a7640000",
  "timestamp": "2016-07-24 20:12:17 UTC"
}
```

My script outputs the following information:

```
"gas"
"gas"
```

But in fact what I'd like is something more akin to this:

```
...
"hash": "0xf2b5b8fb173e371cbb427625b0339f6023f8b4ec3701b7a5c691fa9cef9daf63",    
"gasUsed": "21000",
"hash": "0xf8f2a397b0f7bb1ff212b6bcc57e4a56ce3e27eb9f5839fef3e193c0252fab26"
"gasUsed": "21000"
...
```

I've tried to change it to output the subsequent `group`, but that didn't work.

Comment: You didn't define  any groups in the pattern that's why it didn't work. 0 is always the full match and within that you can you can have match groups by using parenthesis in the pattern.

Comment: who to define groups?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of printing `found`, can't you just print the entire `line` that you found it on?

```
import re
data = open('toy.json', 'r')

for line in data: 
    m = re.search('\"(gas|hash)\"', line)
    if m:
        found = m.group(0)
        print(line.strip())
```

And I changed the regex, so it uses `"(gas|hash)"`

Comment: niiiiiiiice :-)

Answer (score 0):

Here group 2 and group 3 contain the values for "hash" and "gasUsed" respectively:

https://regex101.com/r/IOcdKW/1

The groups should be defined by you :)